# Puppet set Apache Header X-Frame-Options

Tags: apache, puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I want to set the Apache's header X-Frame-Options to "Deny" by adding the following line into the httpd.conf file on a single server using puppetlaps apache module.

```
Header set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
```

I have the YAML file for the server in the ../environments/data/node/server1.yaml I can edit this file to apply the config on this server only but I don't know what to put in it.

How to call the apache module so it can add the above line into the config file?

I tried the following but didn't worked:

```
apache::header::x-frame-options: 'DENY'
```

Update:
Followed the advice below but still not working in my environment, l can't find another way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In Puppet, headers are set in an instance of an `apache::vhost` defined type.

https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apache/7.0.0/reference#headers

You'll either need to create an `apache::vhost` in a manifest

```
apache::vhost { 'example.com':
 [...]
 headers => 'set X-Frame-Options "DENY"',
 [...]
}
```

or use the `apache::vhosts` convenience class to do the same thing in Hiera

```
classes:
  - apache::vhosts

apache::vhosts::vhosts:
  'example.com':
    [...]
    headers: 'set X-Frame-Options "DENY"'
    [...]
```

Comment: Can I do it in the node yaml file? Im not sure how to do the above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that in the node YAML. I'd note you need to flesh out that `apache::vhost::vhosts` hash with a lot of other stuff, which I'm not in a position to give you. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, this didn't work for me. Is there any other way of doing it? Thanks